# Vector subspaces of functions

Tags: functions, vector-spaces

Let $F(R)$ be the set of all functions. Which the following subsets of $F(R)$ are vector subspaces?

(i) $S_1 = \{f \in F(R) : f(\sqrt{2})=0\}$

(ii) $S_2 = \{f \in F(R):f(x)=0, x \in R\}$

(iii) $S_3 = \{f \in F(R):\lim \limits_{x \to 1}f(x)=0 \}$

(iv) $S_4=\{f \in F(R): \exists f'(\pi / 2)\}$

(v) $S_5 = \{f \in F(R):f(0)=1\}$

I know the condition for a subset to be a vector subspace: the zero vector  is in $S$; if $u$ and $v$ are elements of $S$, so is $u+v$; and if $u$ is an element of $S$, so is k$u$. I just can't visualize these conditions in a function space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that the sum $f+g$ is defined pointwise. so all you have to di is to test the conditions that define a vector space $S$.

Condition (1)  $0 \in S$, where $0=0(x)$ is the function such that $0(x)+f(x)=f(x) $ And this means that $0(x)$ is the function that is always null in the given range:

So, as an example in your $S_i$, we have $0(x) \in S_1$ since $0(\sqrt{2}=0$, but $0(x) $ is not an element of $S_5$. You can test for the other $S_i$.

Condition (2) : $f,g \in S \Rightarrow f+g \in S$.

For $S_1$ this is obviously true since $(f+g)(\sqrt{2})=f(\sqrt{2})+g(\sqrt{2})=0+0=0$, but it is obviously false for $S_5$ since $(f+g)(0)=f(0)+g(0)=1+1=2$.

Condition (3) : $f \in S \Rightarrow kf \in S$ where $(kf)(x)=k\cdot f(x)$

This is true for $S_1$ since $(kf)(\sqrt{2})=k \cdot 0=0$, but you can easely see that it is not true for $S_5$.

Now you can solve  the other cases?

Answer (score 1):

I will do $i$ for you. The 0 function is clearly in the set.Assume $f$ and $g$ are in the set. Then $(f+g)(\sqrt{2})=f(\sqrt{2})+g(\sqrt{2})=0$. Further, if $k$ is a scalar, $(kf)(\sqrt{2})=k(f(\sqrt{2}))=k \times 0=0$. But $v$ is not a vector space, as the zero function does not belong to it. So, you can try and check the axioms 1 by 1. If while checking, something seemed really hard to show, then the set might not be a vector space.